# Animate AppBarLayout from the top

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to animate the AppBarLayout from the top, like the Toolbar in [this](https://youtu.be/rTucTiIlQDA) video.

Here's my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/abl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="152dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:titleEnabled="true"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Title.Expanded"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Title.collapsed"
            app:title="Title"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="48dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I was planning to translate AppBarLayout by the negative of its height, then animate it back to `0`.

But for some reason `abl.setTranslationY(-height)` isn't working :(

**Edit**: It works if it is executed after all the views have been laid out (for eg. if executed inside a click listener of a button, it works), but doesn't work in `onCreate`, `onResume` or `onCreateOptions`.

**Edit 2**: I need when the activity starts there should be no appBarLayout and then it should enter from top. Refer to the video.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
private static final float APPBAR_ELEVATION = 14f;

private void AnimateAppBar(final AppBarLayout appBar) {
    appBar.animate()
            .translationY(-appBar.getHeight())
            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
            .setDuration(500)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    appBar.setElevation(0);
                    appBar.animate()
                            .translationY(0)
                            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
                            .setDuration(500)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    appBar.setElevation(APPBAR_ELEVATION);
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}
```

This is the result when you call `AnimateAppBar(appBar);`

[image]

You can change both `Duration` to speed up animation, and set `APPBAR_ELEVATION` to 0 if you don't want the effect to the high at end of the animation.

**EDIT:**

Use this in `onCreate()`

```
animationAppBarDown(appBar);
```

And add this method:

```
private void animationAppBarDown(final AppBarLayout appBar){
    new CountDownTimer(300, 1) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            appBar.setTranslationY(-appBar.getHeight());
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            appBar.animate()
                    .translationY(0)
                    .setDuration(500).start();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: I don't just want to animate the toolbar, i want the whole appBarLayout to enter from the top

Comment: You should have better code style. Just saying. https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

Comment: Yes I know @NikolaDespotoski but is the first solution that came to my mind at the moment..

Comment: @MicheleLacorte I didn't object the solution, but the styling of the code you've written. :)

Comment: There are a million ways to write the same 20 lines of code if you do not like it I can change it ;) @NikolaDespotoski

Comment: Final edit @Jaydeep now is what you wanted right? :D

Comment: @MicheleLacorte can you please try that code in the xml i provided, because it seems like it should work but is not working

Comment: Now I can't, what kind of mistake you have?